# How to find the content type of the application in android

Tags: android, types

How will i be able to find out the content type of an application, 
I have an application i need to be able to know what exactly that application contains, like if it has video or audio or images or just text.

Is there anyway i can find this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: "how will i be able to find out the content type of an application" --  applications do not have content types. "need to be able to know what exactly that application contains" -- what is your definition of the verb "contains"?

Comment: I want to know what my application contains, like for example if you take youtube app, my app should know this contains video. or any music player app it has audio.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, **no** way to find content type of application, because application don't contains content type.